# Mistake in calculating a variable from a plot

Tags: plotting, variable-definitions

I have data from a knife-edge measurement technique, Power vs. knife position, and I want to obtain the beam radius.

```
kf = List[{36.2, 2360.0}, {36.3, 2360.0}, {36.4, 2320.0}, {36.5, 2150}, {36.6, 
   1790}, {36.7, 640}, {36.8, 240}, {36.9, 80}, {37, 20}, {37.1, 0.383}, {37.2, 
   0.628}, {37.3, 0.652}, {37.4, 0.666}, {37.5, 0.668}, {37.6, 0.666}, {37.7, 
   0.653}, {37.8, 0.623}, {37.9, 0.293}, {38.0, 32}, {38.1, 106}, {38.2, 
   475}, {38.3, 1070}, {38.4, 1730}, {38.5, 2250}, {38.6, 2330}, {38.7, 
   2350}, {38.8, 2360}]
```

with `FindFit[kf, {1180 *( 1 - Erf[(Sqrt[2] * x)/w ]) }, {w}, x]` I get a wrong value for `w`. Also if I plot, I get a flat line.

```
Show[ListPlot[kf, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[{1180 (1 - Erf[(Sqrt[2] x)/w])} /. {w -> 0.95}, {x, 37.5, 38.8}, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

How can I obtain `w` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to @Julius I decided to look up knife-edge measurements, and realized I've done them before on laser beams for an optical chopper, I just didn't realize there was a name for them. I was integrating the Gaussian directly, but it turns out Mathematica has a version of `Erf[]` with two arguments. We can use this to fit the data:

```
FindFit[
  kf, 
  {
     1180 (Erf[Sqrt[2] (x - b)/w, Sqrt[2] (x - c)/w] + 2),
     36.5 <= b <= 37,
     38 <= c <= 38.5, 
     0 < w
  }, 
  {b, c, w}, 
  x
]
(* {b -> 36.6545, c -> 38.3139, w -> 0.228245} *)
```

and that gets us:

[image: Fit of kf to 2-argument Erf function.]

I have added `b` and `c` as fitting constants for the edges of the function

**ORIGINAL:**

I don't think your model is correct for your data. First, the plot of `1180(1-Erf[Sqrt[2]x/1])` looks like this:

[image: Plot of 1-Erf.]

But your data looks like this:

[image: Plot of kf data.]

The first thing I notice is that the model needs some kind of offset so that the `Erf[]` function goes to zero around your value. The second thing I notice is that the `Erf[]` function never increases again. You could resolve this by fitting one function to the first half of the data and another function to the second half of the data. I don't know what kind of data you're fitting to, but it does seem odd to me that the model doesn't account for this. Is it well known in your field that this is the correct model, or is there a good reason to use this model?

We can get the model to work nicely for the first half of the data by adding in some constraints. There are some very nice packages out there that are really good at guessing the constraints and/or initial conditions, but you can always make a sufficiently pathological function that your fitting algorithm will fall apart if you don't provide something more than just the model, so it's a good idea to include either constraints on the values, starting points for the values, or both. Notice that I've added `b` in order to shift the data close to the point we're interested in.

```
FindFit[kf[[1 ;; 27]], {1180 (1 - Erf[Sqrt[2] (x - b)/w]), 
  36.5 <= b <= 37.5, 0 < w}, {b, w}, x]
(* {b -> 36.6542, w -> 0.189013} *)
```

Plotting this fit, we get:

[image: Fit of kf data to new model.]

Comment: The model seems fine for a knife-edge measurement, the data is just somehow off.